# Cursing and swearing

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

Cursing and swearing, Michael crawled out of the car.

1. Is it very natural to use 'cursing' and 'swearing' together?
2. Is it ok to use it as in the sentence without adding what he's cursing and swearing at?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask Yes, it's fine to use two verbs.

Comment: RE: 2. It's not obligatory to say what he's swearing _by_, either.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say it's very common (it gets 204 hits in the iWeb corpus, against 17 thousand for *cursing* and 22 thousand for *swearing*, though some of these will have different meanings), but it's certainly possible, and indeed it is an example of a figure of speech - [synonymia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synonymia) - which goes back hundreds of years.

Also, yes, you can use both *curse* and *swear* (in this sense) without a direct or indirect object.